# Key error from a set

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm currently having a key error come up when trying to compile my project. What I'm trying to do is to set all these locations to dfs.  I have looked up python examples but I con't see what is different between what I'm doing here and what they are doing. The error occurs at  dfs[location] =newDF.

Any guidance much appreciated. Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

locations = set(df['NAME'])
dfs = {        "ADA 0.7 SE, MI US", "ADA 1.8 W, MI US", "ALLENDALE 1.3 SSW, MI US",
               "ALLENDALE 2.1 SE, MI US", "ALTO 4.5 SW, MI US", "BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US", 
               "CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US", "COMSTOCK PARK 1.0 NNW, MI US", "COMSTOCK PARK 3.7 NNE, MI US",
               "CUTLERVILLE 1.0 NNE, MI US", "EAST GRAND RAPIDS, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS 2.5 ENE, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS 2.9 NW, MI US",
               "GRAND RAPIDS 3.1 NNE, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS 3.2 S, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS 3.8 SE, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS 4.6 ESE, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS 5.5 SSE, MI US",
               "GRAND RAPIDS 9.6 ESE, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS GERALD R FORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT, MI US", "GRAND RAPIDS SUTRON, MI US", "GRANDVILLE 1.3 WSW, MI US",
               "JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US", "KENTWOOD 1.6 WSW, MI US", "KENTWOOD 1.8 SSE, MI US", "NWSFO GRAND RAPIDS, MI US", "ROCKFORD 0.9 NNE, MI US", "ROCKFORD 5.0 ESE, MI US",
               "ROCKFORD, MI US", "SPARTA 2.8 W, MI US", "WYOMING 0.5 NNE, MI US", "WYOMING 2.2 SW, MI US"}

for location in locations:
    newDF = np.where(df['NAME'] == location)[0]
    dfs[location] =newDF
df.to_csv("average2016.csv")
```

Comment: What key error is occurring, and where?

Comment: Also what is in `Data.csv`?

Comment: Data.csv is a file that I am reading in and the error was occurring dfs[location] =newDF here however I have fixed the issue I believe by turning it into newDF = {location}. If I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Could you post a short snippet of what `Data.csv` looks like, and what your desired output looks like?